# Flutter: JSON data , list under list

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have JSON data file that looks like this, as you can see the email is a list itself:

```
[
    {
        "index": 0,
        "about": "text text text",
        "email": [
            "kjdkffsk@skfjsd.com",
            "kjdkffsk@skfjsd.com",
        ],
        "name": "sample name",
        "picture": "https://kdjfksfjsdklfs.com"
    },
    {
        "index": 1,
        "about": "text text text",
        "email": [
            "kjdkffsk@skfjsd.com",
            "kjdkffsk@skfjsd.com",
        ],
        "name": "sample name ",
        "picture": "https://kdjfksfjsdklfs.com"
    },
    {
        "index": 2,
        "about": "text text text",
        "email": [
            "kjdkffsk@skfjsd.com",
            "kjdkffsk@skfjsd.com",
        ],
        "name": "sample name",
        "picture": "https://kdjfksfjsdklfs.com"
    }
]
```

My code is the following, which is basically a listview builder that gets data from the above JSON. Now when the list is clicked it navigate to the next page where I need to show details of this user.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Users'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

Future _data;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<User>> _getUsers() async {
    var data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/test.json");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data);

    List<User> users = [];

    for (var u in jsonData) {
      User user =
          User(u["index"], u["about"], u["name"], u["email"], u["picture"]);

      users.add(user);
    }

    print(users.length);

    return users;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _data = _getUsers();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _data,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage:
                          NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].picture),
                    ),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                    // subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  DetailPage(snapshot.data[index])));
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;

  DetailPage(this.user);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(user.name),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Text(user.about),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  final int index;
  final String about;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String picture;

  User(this.index, this.about, this.name, this.email, this.picture);
}
```

I wanted to create Listview Builder in the second page for name and the email so that all the emails listed under the name.

can someone help I am not able to generate the second page list especially the email list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check out this example and let me know if it works for you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:json_parsing_example/models.dart';

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final user = userFromJson(jsonString);

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Users'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

Future _data;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<User>> _getUsers() async {
    var data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");

    return userFromJson(data);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _data = _getUsers();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
          future: _data,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage:
                          NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].picture),
                    ),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                    // subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  DetailPage(snapshot.data[index])));
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;

  DetailPage(this.user);

  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.user.name),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                widget.user.name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: widget.user.email.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(widget.user.email[index]),
                ));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your model class :

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final user = userFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<User> userFromJson(String str) => List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));

String userToJson(List<User> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class User {
    User({
        this.index,
        this.about,
        this.email,
        this.name,
        this.picture,
    });

    int index;
    String about;
    List<String> email;
    String name;
    String picture;

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        index: json["index"],
        about: json["about"],
        email: List<String>.from(json["email"].map((x) => x)),
        name: json["name"],
        picture: json["picture"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "index": index,
        "about": about,
        "email": List<dynamic>.from(email.map((x) => x)),
        "name": name,
        "picture": picture,
    };
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you appreciated .But I need to show the user name on the second page above the emails not in the appbar. How can I do this. I mean when running the listview builder, it will show first the name and then a list of emails

Comment: Just check out the code I have made changes using the column as a parent will do and the name on the top and then later comes your list view , and don't forget to add the shrink-wrap to true for listview because you are using the column, so Listview will take the space only based on the child.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support. Highly appreciated

Comment: One more help please: I need to come up with one variable to join all emails like this : `var emailall = widget.user.email.join("\n\n"); ` but this does not work. can please help to fix it and let me know where I put it. I need to use in the the second page

Comment: What do mean by join? Can you elaborate.

Comment: I mean joining (or combining) all the emails under one variable , one under the other. I wanted to use them for sharing function.

Comment: you just want to show it one below the other and on click want to make the share functionality. do you want to click on the single email address or complete card?. It's kind of confusing any pictorial representation would be better.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support, I managed to do it

Answer (score 0):

**First of all:**
You can use either

- **moor**/**moor_flutter** [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor) [flutter_moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor)
- OR
- **built_value** [built_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value)


   To map the json String and generate fromJson/toJson functions.


  Example using moor:
- First, create a moor database (if you have any question I am glad to answer).
- Second, this would be the class you should use.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:db/moordb/database.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart' as json;
import 'package:moor/moor.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@DataClassName("User")
class Users extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().nullable().autoIncrement()();

  @JsonKey("index")
  IntColumn get index => text().nullable()();

  @JsonKey("about")
  TextColumn get about => text().nullable()();

  @JsonKey("email")
  TextColumn get emails => text().map(const EmailConverter()).nullable()();

  @JsonKey("name")
  TextColumn get name => text().nullable()();

  @JsonKey("picture")
  TextColumn get picture => text().nullable()();

  @override
  Set<Column> get primaryKey => {id};
}

class EmailConverter extends TypeConverter<List<String>, String> {
  const EmailConverter ();

  @override
  List<String> mapToDart(String fromDb) {
    if (fromDb == null) {
      return null;
    }
    List _emails = List<String>();
    (jsonDecode(fromDb)).forEach((value) {
      _emails.add(value);
    });
    return _emails;
  }

  @override
  String mapToSql(List<dynamic> value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return jsonEncode(value);
  }
}
```

**Second:**

It is preferred that you send the User object through:

- Navigator arguments [Navigation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)
- or
- An Inherited Widget [Inherited Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zbm3hjPjQMk)

In your case you are passing the object to the widget directly.

In conclusion, it is obvious that the String field email in your User object is not being populated by the decoded data which contains the emails in a List.  (since you are using the Class User).

Note: lose the **new** keyword since it is no longer required in Dart 2